# Heap size increased while scrolling in the Listview Android

Tags: android, android-listview, out-of-memory

I want to develop an application like the facebook application does. (**(i.e.,)**Loading images,Texts,Videos on the list item with infinite list rows). Here i am showing the sampled image(inSamplesize=4) on the listview item to reduce the usage of heap size .

This time, the heap size is keep on increasing while scrolling the listview. I am suggesting that this is because of image object in the list item is not been recycled. If the heap size is keep increasing, The chance of OOM(Out Of Memory) exception may occurs. How to achieve this concept and ensure the chance of OOM exception is less?.

Comment: Check whether are you keeping any references to large objects like bitmaps or mediaplayer, if so find a way to handle them efficiently like caching.

Comment: you must use image loader to load images.
Try this
https://github.com/aalap-shah/Android-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use `view holder` pattern in your `listview's` `adapter` :

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Or do some googling, basically all apps should follow this pattern.

Comment: Hi blaze, if we use the viewholder pattern, the view will not be re-created if the convertview is not null. i understood this concept. But if there is 1000 rows means, viewholder also will keep the view reference and the heap size will increase right?

Comment: @JayaprakashMarshal yes, the heap size will still getting bigger, but a lot of smaller compare to if you inflating the views for each row. Try it first, i did some apps that has heavy-long listview, its working fine.

Comment: sure blaze.I am afraid if it crosses the heap limit. i will try.

Comment: @JayaprakashMarshal If your image is not very huge, it seems you will be find. Lets try it first and let me know :)

Comment: Hi blaze. I tried your solution.It works. I didn't face any issue still. It seems, the bitmap memory is recycled while scrolling. thanks. I have one more doubt. What does happen if we want to cache the image in LruCache but cache memory is full. Whether this will throw any error?

Comment: @JayaprakashMarshal You welcome :) Sorry i dont know about LruCache, feel free yo open a new question about that. Please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Reusing the convertView in getView() of listadapter should solve OOM exception.

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
       }

       ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
       return convertView;
   }
   ```
2. Using a ViewHolder with above will make scrolling fast

   ```
   static class ViewHolder {
       private ImageView imageView;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ViewHolder holder;

       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
       return convertView;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use very large size images, if u are displaying the images in list for thumbs only resize them according to your UI. Android apps only gets less then 20mb for its execution, So using large images exceeds the memory available.

and add **`android:largeHeap="true"`** in application tag of your manifest.